# Iterating over python Dictionary using For Loop and having two values in a single iteration

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
Example: dict = {'one':1 ,'two':2 , 'three':3}
```

I want to use/have two values within single iteration of for loop.  End result should be like this

```
# 1 2 (First iteration)
# 1 3 (Second iteration) 
# 2 1
# 2 3 
# 3 1 
# 3 2
```

Can someone please tell how I can achieve this in python dictionary.

```
for i in dict.values():

  # how do i Access two values in single iteration and to have result like mentioned       above
```

Thanks

Comment: I think my question deals with dictionaries there must be difference in the approach

Comment: what is `dict.values()`?

Comment: Actually i want to access the values only  so i am using this function dict.values()  Example it should be like this x = 1 , y =2  these values will be used as an arguments to another function self.funct(x,y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools
d = {'one':1 ,'two':2 , 'three':3}
l = list(itertools.permutations(d.values(),2))

>>> l
[(3, 2),
 (3, 1),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 1),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 2)]

for x, y in l:
    # do stuff with x and y
```

Comment: Note that python dictionaries are unordered. If order is important, you may want to use OrderedDict, or simply a list.

Comment: Note that the `.keys()` is not required here...

Comment: the OP wants the values so the keys are irrelevant

Comment: All valid comments. Edited to address Jon's and Padraic's comments. Orion's still stands, if that is a requirement of the OP.

Comment: Its working fine. I have a follow up question :

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output order by ordering the permutations of the `dict`s values, eg:

```
from itertools import permutations

dct = {'one':1 ,'two':2 , 'three':3}
for fst, snd in sorted(permutations(dct.itervalues(), 2)):
    print fst, snd # or whatever
```

Answer (score -1):

> Actually i want to access the values only so i am using this function dict.values() Example it should be like this x = 1 , y =2 these values will be used as an arguments to another function self.funct(x,y)

In your comment it seemed like you just wanted both numbers for another function. If you don't mind nested loops, this should suffice:

```
d = {'one':1 ,'two':2 , 'three':3}
dvals = sorted(d.values()

for x in dvals:
  for y in dvals:
    if x != y: 
      self.funct(x,y)
```

Comment: The -1 is for not answering the "having two values in a single iteration," part of the question correct? It seemed to me from his comment that Thomsan amended his goal. If there is another reason for the minus- i.e. a better way of doing it other than the loop or itertools, please let me know.